# Cannot properly set user, group, and group list for `chroot` on macOS?

Tags: terminal, command-line, mojave

I want to `chroot` my current user on macOS 10.14.6 for learning purposes.

I've read `man chroot` and understand that the `-u`, `-g`, and `-G` may be used to specify the user, group, and group list of the chroot'd `command`.

This is the user, group, and group list of my current user:

```
nlykkei-mbp:tmp nlykkei$ id
uid=501(nlykkei) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),502(access_bpf),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
```

After executing the following `chroot`, I would expect that `uid=501(nlykkei), gid=80(admin), groups=80(admin)`, but this is not the case:

```
nlykkei-mbp:tmp nlykkei$ sudo chroot -u nlykkei -g admin -G admin / id
uid=501(nlykkei) gid=20(staff) egid=80(admin) groups=20(staff),502(access_bpf),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
```

How can I properly execute `chroot`, so that `uid=501(nlykkei), gid=80(admin), groups=80(admin)`?

Furthermore, in the man page of `chroot`, why is there a "`-`" in `-user` (same for `-group`)?

`man chroot`:

```
chroot [-u -user] [-g -group] [-G -group,group,...] newroot [command]

...

If the -u, -g or -G options are given, the user, group and group list of the
process are set to these values after the chroot has taken place.  See 
setgid(2), setgroups(2), setuid(2), getgrnam(3) and getpwnam(3).
```